# How to use AWS Xray to trace outgoing HTTP Calls in C#?

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-xray

I'm trying to use AWS Xray on a C# Lambda function to trace outgoing HTTP calls. My code snippet is as such:

```
public class Function : Common.Functions.BaseFunction
{
    public Function()
    {
        AWSSDKHandler.RegisterXRayForAllServices();
        AWSXRayRecorder.InitializeInstance();
    }

    public async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> FunctionHandler(APIGatewayProxyRequest apiGatewayRequest, ILambdaContext context)
    {
         var request = await Validate<CustomerRequestModel>(apiGatewayRequest, redacted_enum_type1, redacted_enum_type2);

          var userService = new UserService();
          var user = await userService.Get(request);
    }
}
```

`userService.get(request)` is an abstracted method that gives a customer request model. Within this method, there is a call to dynamo DB. When I run my lambda with this code, I only get the overarching invocation of the whole function, but I want sub segments detailing the outgoing HTTP call when I run userService.get, including the dynamo DB call.

I tried using`await AWSXRayRecorder.Instance.TraceMethodAsync("User Service get",() => userService.Get(request));` but it only gives me the invocation for userService.get and not the dynamo DB call. Meanwhile, I am unable to use the recommended methods [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-dotnet-httpclients.html) because I do not have access to the endpoints in user service. How should I modify my code such that I am able to show both the invocation of user service as well as the dynamo DB call?

Comment: Your server is a two port application.  Port 1 is the HTTP client server connection.  Port 2 is the server to dynamo DB call.  See following : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/implementing-logging-monitoring-cloudwatch/application-tracing-xray.html?force_isolation=true